# Cannot connect React Redux

Tags: reactjs

[image: redux]

[image: code]

[image: code]

I followed an insturction provided on the documentation. But, the redux dev tool is saying no store found. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In the store file, you have to write the following code:

```
import appMiddleware from './middlewares/app.middleware';
import appReducers from './reducers/app.reducer';


const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(appReducers, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...appMiddleware)));
window.store = store;
```